# Creating an SQL query when the values to be used in the query are unknown

Tags: php, sql

I have some search functionality that works with 3 drop down boxes.  Based on the criteria chosen, a profile is returned.  The 3 drop downs are:

- County
- Constituency
- Gender

Now I am trying to build a query but have just realised that actually a person does not have to choose an option from each drop down and nor do I want them to.

So for instance I do not want to disable the search button until an option is selected from each drop down.

Having chosen a value from any drop down, and possibly having no value selected from any drop down at all, and just clicking the search button, I am trying to understand how I can cope with the unknown combinations.

My first thought was that I could use something like a truth table but I imagine this is simply overkill and in fact this is a very common piece of functionality.

Then I thought maybe I could have something like:

```
$county = "$_GET['county'];";
$constituency = "$_GET['constituency'];";
$gender = "$_GET['gender'];";
```

Then I could check to see if they are empty and somehow use this value, e.g.

```
if($county !== '') {
  ???SOMEHOW MAKE USE OF THIS IN AN SQL QUERY???
  PERHAPS PASS IT TO ANOTHER PARAMETER
  $sqlparams = "county = '$county'";
}

SELECT * FROM profile
WHERE {$sqlparams};
```

I think I'm on the right tracks but could use some guidance.

All help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This should do want you want, I think.

```
<?php
$tooLookFor = array("county", "constituency", "gender");
foreach($tooLookFor as $key){
    if(isset($_GET[$key]) && strlen($_GET[$key])>0){
        $queryParams[] = $key.'="'.$_GET[$key].'"';
    }
}
$query = "SELECT * FROM profile WHERE ".implode(' AND ', $queryParams);
?>
```

Comment: You beat me to it -- however, I'd like to suggest simplifying the if condition into `!empty($_GET[$key])`.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like:

```
$county = $_GET['county'];
$constituency = $_GET['constituency'];
$gender = $_GET['gender'];

$sqlparams = array();

if($county !== '') {
    $sqlparams[] = "county = '$county'";
}
if($constituency !== '') {
    $sqlparams[] = "constituency = '$constituency'";
}
if($gender !== '') {
    $sqlparams[] = "gender = '$gender'";
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM profile";

if (count($sqlparams) > 0) {
    $query .= " WHERE " . implode(" AND ", $sqlparams); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with something like this:

```
$where = array();

//repeat as needed
$where[$column] = $value;

$where2 = array();
foreach($where as $key => $value){
    $where2[] = "$key = '$value'";
}

$where_string = implode(' AND ', $where2);
```

`$where_string` will have the string to insert after `WHERE`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are on the right track, you're just not at the right switch yet. ;)

You can't build the query until you know what you have to work with. So first, in your validation, determine (as you are doing) with the key words actually are and what fields they represent. Presumably these map to fields in tables, maybe 3 tables? Point is, your query will need to be dynamically built.